# Split average reviews php

Tags: php

I m using a code to display average review from amazon to my website with the ASIN code. All works perfectly but i just want to split "4.5" and "étoiles" to show only "4.5" number (see exemple).

How I can do this ?

```
    <?php
$url = 'hxxps://www.amazon.fr/gp/customer-reviews/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=dpx_acr_pop_?contextId=dpx&asin=B01N05ZMTK';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</span>" , $first_step[1] );
echo $second_step[1];
    ?>
```

By the way, do you have a solution to transform "4.5" in stars icons ?

Comment: Why did you tag `preg_match`? You do not seem to be using `regex`.

Comment: I don't know, I thought preg_match was the solution... Can you help me with regex ?

Comment: What is the input string? Please provide a test case and what you tried to obtain that value.

Comment: This code give me "4.5 étoiles sur 5" i want to display only "4.5" number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, when you want to extract something from structured data, use the structure and not a direct string approach. In your case use DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$stars = explode(' ', ltrim($xp->evaluate('string(//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-secondary"])')))[0];
echo $stars;
```

Then you only have to trim and split the string to extract 4.5.

[demo](https://3v4l.org/slHA4)

Note that it can also fully be done with XPath:

```
$stars = $xp->evaluate('substring-before(normalize-space(//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-secondary"])," ")');
```